# "exotic" css layout - left fixed static, right fluid scrollable containing mixed elements

Tags: css, layout

I am having troubles to achieve quite an "exotic" layout which is some kind of a "nested" layout where the HEADER and Footer are actually part of the right column (or "frame"):

```
- Left column - Fixed,Static
- Right column - Fluid/liquid/scrollable
--- Header - fixed 
--- left/main fluid/liquid
--- Right/sidebar - fixed
```

visually it should be something like that :

[image: Example]

so basically the yellowish area is static, fixed and always in view.

The green frame is scrollable , and it contains the header, footer and sidebar.

I have searchd all major "css-layout-galleries" sites, but I did not encountered a solid solution yet . (most have the header at the top of the page)

My main problem is to achieve a **bulletproof** method that will work on **ALL major OS & browsers** (Firefox 3.6 - 6 , IE 6-9 , Opera , safari > Mac, Win, Linux)

Right now, (as usually expected) IE is always giving me a hard time, although in some layout experiments , also firefox is giving an unexpected different results (between Vr. 3.6 and 5 for example)

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you close, with IE 6+ compatibility if you do something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xg7gs/).

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="side">
    Side content. Fixed width. Floats left with a negative margin.
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Main content...fills the rest of the width (fluid)
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.outer {
    margin-left: 100px;
    background: red;
}

div.outer div.side {
    display: inline; /* for IE 6 */
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    background: yellow;
}

div.outer div.main {
    min-height: 200px;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for responding. unfortunately , your proposal does not apply to my needs . it might be that you misunderstood the requirements. in your layout , the left column in not fixed, and even after applying position:fixed;height:100% - it is scrolling with the page (IE6) . Moreover - the inner divisions , when applied (missing in your example) present other difficulties. Thanks anyhow, and any furthe advice will be greatly appreciated. as for now , scumah´s proposal was much closer , and I still hope I can modify it to suite the needs ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PBDaQ/)) I think that's pretty much what you need.

HTLM:

```
<div id="left-col">left col</div>

<div id="container">

    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
        main
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left-col {
    width: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    background: yellow;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#container {
    margin-left: 50px;
    background: black;
}
#header {
    background: green;
}
#main {
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
}
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    background: pink;
}
#footer {
    background: red;
}
```

It's working in FF, Chrome and Opera in Mac. I can't test it in any Windows browser right now, so IE might be a problem here :P Anyway, in case this works, you'll still need to fix left-col's and sidebar's height to be 100% somehow. But before that, you can give this layout a try.

Comment: Thank for the reply ... I have tried a very similar solution already , unfortunately : 1. it does not work in IE6 (yes, we all want to kill IE6 , but it is still much alive especially in asia - ie6+7 =almost 20%...) 2. the layout looks ok when blank, but fill the content and the sidebar hides the main area (easily fixed with margin-left: samevalue_px;) 3. if there is not enough content on page - the footer hides behind the sidebar. anyhow , thanks again for the help ! if I will find a solution - I will post it .